# ML.NET can't use Nullable types in IDataView? How do I handle missing data?

Tags: c#, ml.net

I am attempting some machine learning in ML.NET to predict prices.

My input data has some holes, so I was expecting to model these with nullable types:

```cs
public int? ScreenHeight { get; set; }
```

When I transform my data into this structure, however, I get an error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Could not determine an IDataView type for member ScreenHeight '

After reading [the documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/IDataViewDesignPrinciples.md) it seems that nullable Types might not be supported in ML.Net.

Can anyone offer advice on how to approach this? I understand that I could estimate any missing data, but in this case that would just be a complete guess.

For context, this line is doing the transform and throwing the error:

```cs
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CustomMapping(mapping, contractName: null);
```

Comment: Try using just float. ML.NET may be able to handle missing values on it’s own. If the performance isn’t good I have other suggestions :)

Comment: but ML.NET will not accept nullable float - ...so the issue of missing values remains.

Comment: Just use a regular `float` instead of making it nullable.

Comment: ...but I have some values missing - that's the point.

Comment: Yes, and ML.NET can handle some missing values. Have you tried it? If it's erroring or giving poor performance you can use the replace missing values transform - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/prepare-data-ml-net#replace-missing-values

Comment: yes, thankyou, but as I already stated - if I have to fill in any missing values then they would be a complete guess in this case, and that doesn't seem like a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace missing values with `float.NaN`. To validate that value is missing see [`IndicateMissingValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.extensionscatalog.indicatemissingvalues?view=ml-dotnet#microsoft-ml-extensionscatalog-indicatemissingvalues(microsoft-ml-transformscatalog-microsoft-ml-inputoutputcolumnpair())).